# How to connect computers to a network printer behind a router?

Tags: networking, router, ip, network-printer

### General question:

How to connect computers to an IP printer behind a router?

### Particular question:

How to connect C-1 and C-2 to PRI?

### What? Where?

```
            [ISP]
              |
              | -> IPs:200.X.X.X/other configs:DC
              |
            [R-1]
              |
              | -> IPs:10.1.X.X locked by MAC,M:255.0.0.0,G:10.1.0.1
   |¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
   |                    |
 [PRI] IP:10.1.7.7    [R-2] IP: 10.1.0.1,MAC:A
                        |
                        | -> IPs:192.168.1.X,M:255.255.255.0,G:192.168.1.1
            |¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
            |                      |
          [C-1] IP:192.168.1.2   [C-2] IP:192.168.1.3,MAC:A

Glossary and details:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- IP: IP.
- IPs: Some IP range.
- M: Mask.
- G: Gateway.
- MAC:A: A MAC address that I will not inform you :)
- DC: Don't care.

- ISP: Internet Service Provider (not so much details about it on that case).
- R-1: A real router or some concatenated so IP range bellow that block is 10.1.X.X
       and above is ISP. The provided IPs are provided by MAC. As all available
       addresses are in use, you must clone an existing one to join with a new
       device (and to disconnect the cloned one).
- PRI: An network printer (some people here call that IP printer).
- R-2: A TP-LINK TL-WR340G, mine wireless router (since my computer does not have
       ethernet input, it is my ethernet-wifi adapter :), admin access, MAC address
       cloned from C-2 (MAC:A). I've to configure 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.2 as DNS
       addresses, other wise I cannot connect C-1 and C-2 to Internet.
- C-1: My computer, a CCE XLE-425 (remember: no ethernet input), with Windows 7,
       admin access.
- C-2: another computer with better configs than mine, MAC:A, Windows XP.
```

### Requirements:

I want to print, to access Internet and to do it myself (no need to call network admin men in black people).

Pay attention to MAC clones and DNS info.

Comment: what tcp port do you want to use for the printer?

Comment: It's not clear from your description/diagram whether R-2 and C-2 have different MAC addresses or not.

Comment: @MikePennington, you choose the port :)

Comment: @ultrasawblade, they have equal MAC addresses. I called that address only MAC:A, but in real it is something like 11-22-33-44-55-66 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

After @MikePennington said something about the "port", I got to R-2 settings. There, I could see Virtual Servers config:

[image: Virtual Servers config]

On printer driver properties, I could see also that the port used for network connection was 9100:

[image: port used for network connection]

So it was too easy as configuring ports for game servers on computers with routed connection (hmmm... why I do not thought it before?):

```
Configure R-2:
- for C-1:
    - service port: 9100
    - IP address: 192.168.1.2
    - Protocol: ALL
- for C-2:
    - service port: 9101
    - IP address: 192.168.1.3
    - Protocol: ALL

- Configure C-1:
    - none

- Configure C-2:
    - printer TCP/IP RAW port: 9101

- Reboot R-2 (I forget it on first time and did not see any result. In another try,
              I succeeded!)
```