# How to access shared folders of computers separated by a router?

Tags: networking, router, ip, shared-folders

Question based on a solved question I made before: [How to connect computers to a network printer behind a router?](https://superuser.com/questions/431076/how-to-connect-computers-to-a-network-printer-behind-a-router)

### General question:

How to access shared folders of computers separeted by a router?

### Particular question:

How to access shared folders from C-3 using C-1 or C-2 computer and vice-versa?

### What? Where?

```
            [ISP]
              |
              | -> IPs:200.X.X.X/other configs:DC
              |
            [R-1]
              |
              | -> IPs:10.1.X.X locked by MAC,M:255.0.0.0,G:10.1.0.1
   |¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
   |                    |                           |
 [PRI] IP:10.1.7.7    [R-2] IP: 10.1.0.1,MAC:A    [C-3] IP:10.1.7.8
                        |
                        | -> IPs:192.168.1.X,M:255.255.255.0,G:192.168.1.1
            |¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
            |                      |
          [C-1] IP:192.168.1.2   [C-2] IP:192.168.1.3,MAC:A

Glossary and details:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- IP: IP.
- IPs: Some IP range.
- M: Mask.
- G: Gateway.
- MAC:A: A MAC address that I will not inform you :)
- DC: Don't care.

- ISP: Internet Service Provider (not so much details about it on that case).
- R-1: A real router or some concatenated so IP range bellow that block is 10.1.X.X
       and above is ISP. The provided IPs are provided by MAC. As all available
       addresses are in use, you must clone an existing one to join with a new
       device (and to disconnect the cloned one).
- PRI: An network printer (some people here call that IP printer).
- R-2: A TP-LINK TL-WR340G, mine wireless router (since my computer does not have
       ethernet input, it is my ethernet-wifi adapter :), admin access, MAC address
       cloned from C-2 (MAC:A). I've to configure 10.0.1.1 and 10.0.1.2 as DNS
       addresses, other wise I cannot connect C-1 and C-2 to Internet.
- C-1: My computer, a CCE XLE-425 (remember: no ethernet input), with Windows 7,
       admin access.
- C-2: another computer with better configs than mine, MAC:A, Windows XP.
- C-3: another computer, Windows XP
```

### Requirements:

I want to continue printing normally, as in solution of mentioned solved question (I redirected 9100 and 9101 port traffic to computers C-1 and C-2 respectively), to access Internet and to do it myself (no need to call network admin men in black people).

I would like to access shared folders as easy as using \\C-1, \\C-2, \\C-3 or \\x.x.x.x and te name of shared folder, as in common sharing...

Pay attention to MAC clones and DNS info.

### What I think that can solve the problem:

Well, in mentioned solved question, I redirected ports related to IP printer to computers I wanted to use it. I think redirecting ports to correct ones - I don't know which ones - solves that too...

Comment: Port redirection configures a "Many-to-One" relationship. You need "Many-to-Many" inorder to achieve this, routing. So port redirection won't work in this matter. Does R-2 has a routing config as "dest:10.0.0.0 mask:255.0.0.0 gateway:10.1.0.1" and R-1 has as "dest:192.168.1.0 mask:255.255.255.0 gateway:10.1.0.1" ?

Comment: No and I don't know how to perform something like that :)

Comment: Change wireless router from NAT to a bridge (Non DHCP; Many-to-Many) :) What is the model name and number on your wireless router?

Comment: It is a problem, because I could not see how to change TP-LINK TL-WL440G to bridge mode :(

Comment: Do you have a link to the manual. I do not get any results on google?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled: TL-WR340G

Comment: Sorry for the response time I was busy with phone call :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The WAN port *(blue port)* will not be used, plug it with tape to avoid confusion and accidents. This is normal for some models.

1. **Configure wireless router as Access Point**

   1.1 Power up the wireless router *(R-2)*

   1.2 Reset to factory state *(Consult your wireless router's manual on how to do a factory reset)*

   1.3 Connect a network cable from a computer to one of the LAN ports *(yellow ports)* on the wireless router *(R-2)*

   1.4 Reboot the computer

   1.5 On the computer, open a web browser and type: http://192.168.1.1/. The **username** is **admin** and the **password** is **admin**

   1.6 Go to **DHCP Settings**, select "**Disable DHCP Server**" and click Save

   1.7 Go to **Network Settings**, select "**LAN**", change the "**IP Address**" to an un-occupied IP address within your local area network *(e.g. 10.1.7.200)*. Click Save

   1.8 The wireless router *(R-2)* will reboot itself and your computer will loose connection to the wireless router *(R-2)*
2. **Setup the Access Point**

   2.1 Connect a network cable from your primary router *(R-1)* to the LAN ports *(yellow ports)* on the wireless router *(R-2)*

   2.2 Connect the computer to your primary network *(10.1.X.X)*

   2.3 Reboot the computer

   2.4 Open a web browser and type: http://10.1.7.200/. The **username** is **admin** and the **password** is **admin**

   2.5 You have now re-establish connection to your wireless router *(R-2)*

   2.6 Set the wireless SSID on the wireless router *(R-2)*. If your primary router *(R-1)* have a wireless setup your can use the same SSID for the wireless router *(R-2)* *(or a different SSID if you choose)*

   2.7 Select an appropriate wireless channel on the wireless router *(R-2) (avoid using the same channel as your primary router (R-1); also avoid using your neighbours wireless channels)*

**Source:** http://pigtail.azurewebsites.net/tp-link/index.html

Comment: @kokbira Did it work?